# Why do we have to add -2 to a string when performing operation in assembly language?

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16

```
Data Segment
    str1 db 'MADAME','$' 
    strlen1 dw $-str1  ;calculating the length of the string
  strrev db 20 dup(' ')
  s1 db 'String is:','$'
  NEWLINE DB 10,13,"$"
  str_palin db 'String is Palindrome.','$'
  str_not_palin db 'String is not Palindrome.','$'
Data Ends

Code Segment
  Assume cs:code, ds:data

  Begin:

    mov ax, data
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov cx, strlen1
    add cx, -2

    lea si, str1
    lea di, strrev

    add si, strlen1
    add si, -2
     mov ah, 09h
     lea dx, s1
     int 21h
     mov ah, 09h
     lea dx, str1
     int 21h
     MOV AH,09H
        LEA DX,NEWLINE
        INT 21H
    L1:
       mov al, [si]
       mov [di], al
       dec si
       inc di
       loop L1
       mov al, [si]
       mov [di], al
       inc di
       mov dl, '$'
       mov [di], dl
       mov cx, strlen1

    Palin_Check:
       lea si, str1
       lea di, strrev
       repe cmpsb
       jne Not_Palin

    Palin:
       mov ah, 09h
       lea dx, str_palin
       int 21h
       jmp Exit

    Not_Palin:
       mov ah, 09h
       lea dx, str_not_palin
       int 21h

    Exit:
       mov ax, 4c00h
       int 21h
Code Ends
End Begin
```

Comment: You want a pointer to the last character in the string. Normally that's of course  `start+length-1` due to zero based indexing. It becomes `-2` because you have a `$` at the end that you don't want to process.

Comment: You don't actually have to `add` at runtime, that's just poorly written code.  You could do `mov cx, strlen1 - 2`.  (Oh nvm, `strlen1` is a value stored in memory, not an `equ` constant, so you can't do that. 
 That's also silly.)  It's also always better to use `mov si, OFFSET str1` instead of `lea si, str1`, because it's smaller and can run on more execution ports.

Comment: It's also pointless to make a reversed copy of a string if you just want to check for palindromes: better to start at both ends with pointers that meet in the middle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First instance of adding -2 (`add cx, -2`)

Consider

> ```
> mov cx, strlen1
> add cx, -2        <-- Can be avoided totally
> ```

and also

> ```
> L1:
>  mov al, [si]
>  mov [di], al
>  dec si
>  inc di
>  loop L1
>  mov al, [si]     <-- Should stay inside the loop
>  mov [di], al     <-- Should stay inside the loop
>  inc di           <-- Should stay inside the loop
> ```

Because of how *strlen1* was defined (`strlen1 dw $-str1`) the `add cx, -2` (Why is this not simply `sub cx, 2` ?) does not give the correct length of the string. You get 1 too little. Later because of this, your *L1* loop has to be appended with 3 extra instructions!

---

### Second instance of adding -2 (`add si, -2`)

> ```
> lea si, str1
> add si, strlen1
> add si, -2
> ```

Here again, why prefer `add si, -2` over the more readable `sub si, 2`?
Because of how *strlen1* was defined (`strlen1 dw $-str1`) the `add si, strlen1` will make `SI` point **behind** the terminating $ character.
Subtracting 1 will make `SI` point  **at** the terminating $ character and so **behind** the last character of the string.
Subtracting 2 will make `SI`point **at** the last character of the string.

---

### Suggestion

Much of the above problems would not exist if you redefined *strlen1* so that it **does not include the terminating $ character**. When people talk about *the length of a string* they rarely include any terminating character in the count. Such a character (be it $ or zero) is not really *part* of the string

```
strlen1 dw $ - str1 - 1  ;Length of the string
```

---

To see everything in context:

```
 mov  ah, 09h
 mov  dx, s1
 int  21h
 mov  ah, 09h
 mov  dx, str1
 int  21h
 mov  ah, 09h
 mov  dx, NEWLINE
 int  21h

 cld                 ;To be absolutely safe
 mov  cx, strlen1    ;The improved definition! db 'MADAME','$' => 5
 mov  di, strrev
 mov  si, str1
 add  si, cx         ;Now points behind the last character ('E')
L1:
 dec  si
 mov  al, [si]
 stosb               ;Equivalent to "mov [di], al" "inc di"
 dec  cx
 jnz  L1
 mov  byte ptr [di], '$'
```

Do note these details:

- I've cleanly separated the code that displays to the screen from the code that performs the reversing.
- By placing the `dec si` instruction **before** reading at `[SI]` (We call this *pre-decrementing*), one instruction could be shaved off before the loop start at *L1*.
- I've replaced every `lea` by `mov`. The result is the same, but the code is 1 byte shorter. Each time.
- I've replaced the slow `loop` instruction by equivalent code `dec cx` `jnz L1`.
- I've replaced the pair of instructions `mov [di], al` `inc di` by just 1 equivalent instruction `stosb`. I could do this because the `ES` register was setup and I've cleared the direction flag (DF). Your `repe cmpsb` also depended on the DF=0.
- I've replaced the pair of instructions that write a new $ terminator by just 1 instruction `mov byte ptr [di], '$'`.